# Cassandra: "Unable to complete the operation against any hosts" during session.execute()

Tags: python, cassandra, cql

Cassandra version: 1.2.2
Thrift API version: 19.35.0
CQL supported versions: 2.0.0,3.0.1 (default: 3.0.1)
cassandra-driver for python 3.4
running cassandra/bin/cassandra with sudo

**Code sample**:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect()    # 1
session.execute("use test")    # 2
cluster.shutdown()
```

**Error message for # 2:**
session.execute("use test")
File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1581, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute
File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3145, in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to complete the operation against any hosts', {})

**Confusion**:
Since there's no error in # 1 in the code sample, the connection seems to be fine. But I don't quite understand why the query execution fails.

Comment: which 1.2 version?

Comment: 1.2.2 I have edited my post to include the information.

Comment: does keyspace `test` contain any data?

Comment: Yes it does. It has a bunch of column families (tables) with a ton of data. Keyspace was created using cassandra-cli and I used pycassa to populate the database.

Comment: @yang5 Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Guys, have any of you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify contact points for you cluster e.g:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2'])
session = cluster.connect()
```

More details on [datastax documentation](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html)

Comment: It's a single local node and by default the contact point is set to 127.0.0.1.